# Facebook does not load in PySide qwebview

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pyside, qwebview

I have been trying to implement a browser using PySide and QWebView. However the browser does not load www.facebook.com. I can load other https websites like google so I guess SSL is working alright. 
The same problem persists when using http://code.google.com/p/foobrowser/ or the sample browser included with PySide. What is the problem?

Comment: What happens? Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors. It just doesn't load the webpage. The view stays blank.

Comment: Does Facebook use HTML5 or Flash?

Comment: It doesn't even load the homepage http://www.facebook.com/. I have no idea whether it uses flash or HTML5 but i would think not on the homepage. Flash works on my browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - in my case it was related to ssl errors.
Handling the *sslErrors* signal fixed the problem:

```
m_view = new QWebView(parent);
connect(
  m_view->page()->networkAccessManager(),
  SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
  this, 
  SLOT(sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & ))
);
```

and the slot:

```
void myClass::sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply* qnr, const QList<QSslError> & errlist)
{
    qnr->ignoreSslErrors();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to achieve this in PySide? Trying but sslErrors is never called: https://gist.github.com/rafaelcgo/c07a28a35f6e7166d465

Answer (score 0):

After the [POODLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) vulnerability was discovered, some sites dropped SSLv3.

My version of PySide (1.1.1), on Windows 8.1, has `PySide.QtNetwork.QSsl.SslProtocol.SslV3` as the Default protocol.

To solve the problem, you need to change the `QSslConfiguration` of the `NetworkAccessManager` to use TLS.

```
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply, QSslConfiguration, QSsl


class HtmlFrame(QFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QFrame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.webview = QWebView()

    # Developer extras settings to debug Webview
    # QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

    self._network_manager = FNetworkManager()
    self.webview.page().setNetworkAccessManager(self._network_manager)
    url = "https://www.facebook.com"
    self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

class FNetworkManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
  def __init__(self):
    QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
    # bind a custom virtual function to createRequest
    self.createRequest = self._create_request

  def _create_request(self, operation, request, data):
    ssl_config = QSslConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
    ssl_config.setProtocol(QSsl.TlsV1)
    request.setSslConfiguration(ssl_config)

    reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, operation, request, data)
    return reply
```

Credits to https://github.com/integricho/ and https://github.com/integricho/path-of-a-pyqter/

Comment: On my system (PySide 1.2.1), when I try to import QSslConfiguration I get ImportError: cannot import name QSslConfiguration. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem to load Facebook in PySide qwebview, maybe it's an issue of your platform.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import platform
import PySide
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView

print(PySide.__version__) # output: 1.1.1
print(PySide.QtCore.__version__) # output: 4.8.3
print(platform.platform()) # output: Linux-3.5.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.10-quantal

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("https://www.facebook.com"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

HTH

Comment: Doesn't work with a clean install; must have some pre-existing condition that makes it work for you.

Comment: An answer that is just "I don't have this problem, therefor your problem must not exist" is not helpful to anyone.